# Algorithm to produce a list of ascending numbers

Tags: java, algorithm

I would like to ask a question about algorithms:

A and B are two ordered lists. I want to merge them into a third list C that will also be ordered. For example, if A= [2,4,7] and B = [4, 5, 8, 9, 10] then C = [2, 4, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]. I must start off by saying that as long as A and B have items not copied to C, a certain process continues. What I fail to understand is this:

i) the first item in list A (called "First(A)", which has the value 2) is smaller than "First(B)", which is 4. So the first item in list (C), called "First(C)", is equal to 2. But the second item in list (C) (called "Second(C)") is the value that you get when you compare First(B) and second(A) -- they both have the same value of 4, so you use second(A) as the value of second(C). But remember, First(B) (which is 4) has still not been used, so you compare First(B) with Third(A), and so Third(C)=First(B). I do not know how to use this concept in my algorithm, see below.

ii) Once all the items in the shorter list (ie. list A) has been used up, I must simply insert the remaining items of the longer list (ie. list B) into list (C). How exactly do I include this in my algorithm?

My hopelessly inadequate algorithm so far is:

```
          while(A and B have items NOT copied to C) {
             if (First(A) < First(B)) then (Return: First(C) = First(A))
               else if (First(A) > First(B)) then (Return: First(C) = First(B))

             First(A) := Next(A)
             First(B) := Next(B)
             First(C) := Next(C)
             }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic solution for all numeric types:

```
public static <T extends Number> T[] mergeSortedArrays (T[] A, T[] B)
{

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;

    T[] C = new T [A.length + B.length];

    for (z = 0 ; x < A.length && y < B.length ; z++)
    {
        if (A[x] < B[y])
            C[z++] = A[x++];
        else
            C[z++] = B[y++];
    }

    while (x < A.length)
        C[z++] = A[x++];

    while (y < B.length)
        C[z++] = B[y++];

    return C;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is the `merge` part of a `merge-sort` algorithm. The links below will give you an in-depth explanation on how to do it.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)
[Princeton Edu](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/22mergesort/Merge.java.html)
[Colorado Edu](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/applications/Mergesort.java)

Comment: Just looked up what merge-sort algorithm is on Wikipedia. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can only move forward on the list you copied an item from. Also, you should remove the second if as you ignore when `First(A)==First(B)`. Here is some code (which is not Java, but adapted to your pseudocode)

```
while(A and B have items NOT copied to C) {
  if (First(A) < First(B)) then 
  (
    First(C) := First(A)
    First(A) := Next(A)
  )
  else 
  (
    First(C) := First(B))
    First(B) := Next(B)
  )
  First(C) := Next(C)
  }
```

Comment: That is very succinct and easily understood. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, it's easier to think of the problem in the terms of indexes. You use two indexes (position indicators), one for each list, and go over them until you finish both lists:

```
List<Integer> listA = ...
List<Integer> listB = ...

int sizeA = listA.size();
int sizeB = listB.size();

int indexA = 0;
int indexB = 0;

List<Integer> resultList = new ArrayList<> (sizeA + sizeB);

// Start going over both lists:
while (indexA < sizeA && indexB < sizeB) {
    Integer elemA = listA.get(indexA);
    Integer elemB = listB.get(indexA);

    // Add the smaller element to the result list
    if (elemA <= elemB) {
        resultList.add(elemA);
        ++indexA;
    } else {
        resultList.add(elemB);
        ++indexB;
    }
}

// Now we're finished with one of the lists
// So we just copy the remaining elements of the other list:    
if (indexA == sizeA) {
    for (; indexB < sizeB; ++indexB) {
        resultList.add(listB.get(indexB));
    }
} else {
    for (; indexA < sizeA; ++indexA) {
        resultList.add(listB.get(indexA));
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, I see what you're doing. Took me some time, but I understand now. Thanks, Mureinik.

Answer (score 1):

You Have 2 sorted Lists `A` and `B` and want to merge when into `c`

LOGIC

`int i =0`

`int j = 0`

`int k = ( sizeof(A[])/sizeof(A[1]) ) + sizeof(B[])/sizeof(B[1])   //total number of elements`

`initailize C[k]`

`k = 0`

`while(A[i]!=NULL && B[j]!=NULL)`

```
{
  if ( (A[i] < B[j]) && (A[i] != NULL ))
  {
    C[k] = A[i]
    i++
    k++
  }
  if( B[j] < A[i] && ( B[j] != NULL) )
  {
    C[k] = B[j]
    k++
    j++ 
  }
}
```

You might have to put a condition to check that you are not incremention i or j or k beyond the list size.

Comment: OK, the "not null arrays" was exactly what I was looking for -- thanks v much Ansh.